# Access Mongodb data before updating schema mongoose

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

I am currently trying to write code using mongoose and mongodb where I access some data from mongodb, save the data into a variable, update the new schema with the variable + 1, and then re-save it. I have this code so far, but it is not working for me. Is there a way that I can do this? Thanks.

```js
  let user = message.author;
      const postModel = mongoose.model('Users', { userid: Number, posts: Number });
     let data = postModel.find({userid: user.id})
     console.log(data.posts)
const posts = new postModel({ userid: user.id, posts: data.posts++});
posts.save().then(() => console.log('saved'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Change these two lines

`const posts = new postModel({ userid: user.id, posts: data.posts++}); posts.save().then(() => console.log('saved'));`

to

`postModel.update({ userid: user.id}, {'$set' : {posts: data.posts++}}).then(() => console.log('saved'));`

and try it.

Comment: CastError: Cast to Number failed for value "NaN" at path "posts"

Comment: when you run data.posts it turns out undefined. any idea why?

Comment: Could you share with me your full code? Need to analysis full code.

Comment: Here's the full code: https://hastebin.com/uwujofapir.js